# MySQL Count Total No of Rows from Show Column Names of Temporary Table

Tags: mysql, procedure, temporary

In MySQL Procedure I want count rows from a Temporary Table which created from a dynamic Query ie.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_Tbl as select * from  dynamic_tbl;
```

Desc Temporary tmp_Tbl;
say Field have 15 Rows so save into a session variable @TotCols

again Create Temporary Table from a dynamic Query:
Desc Temporary tmp_Tbl;
say Field have 4 Rows so save into a session variable @TotCols

Answer (score -1):

In the body of your stored routine, please try:

```
SET @create_tmp_table_sql = CONCAT(
    'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_tbl AS ',
    'SELECT * FROM dynamic_tbl'
);
PREPARE create_tmp_table_stmt FROM @create_tmp_table_sql;
EXECUTE create_tmp_table_stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE create_tmp_table_stmt;

SET @TotCols = (SELECT Count(*) FROM tmp_tbl);
```

Comment: In the question i need how much total columns of temporary table.